# Downloading an excel file from aws s3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need a service to download an excel file from Amazon S3. It should also work on all applications like chrome, firefox and IE.

```
    const s3 = new aws.S3();

    s3.config.update({
        region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
        accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });

    const S3_BUCKET = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME;

    const params = {
        Bucket: `${S3_BUCKET}`,
        Key: `${name}.xlsx`,
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            message.error('Not able to download file. Please try again later.');
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            let blob = new Blob([data.Body], {
                type: data.ContentType,
            });
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.click();
            link.download = name + '.xlsx';
            message.success('File download successfully.');
        }
    });
};
```

But this is donwloading a zip file containing xml files. Not sure why.
**I just want to download the file, not parse it**

Comment: A SpreadsheetML or .xlsx file is a zip file (a package) containing a number of "parts" (typically UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded) or XML files

Comment: http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php#:~:text=xlsx%20file%20is%20a%20zip,the%20OOXML%20standard%20ECMA%2D376.

Comment: its not recommended use aws credentials in the frontend, because the users can see it from the page source. Please consider using pre-signed urls which can give temporary access up to 7 days. the pre-signed urls is generated in a secure back end such as nodejs and sent to the frontend . then the url can be used to download the file from the frontend

Comment: @ArunK Then how to convert to zip file to the required .xlsx file. Searched a lot but can't find. Thanks for your help.